What Excel function would I use to bold a string in an Excel cell?
I'm concatenating two strings and I want one of them to be bold.
"Title" & ":Subtitle"

I want it to appear as Title:Subtitle
I tried =TEXT("Title", "b") & "Subtitle", which I've read is the way to do it. But it didn't change the formatting.
I'm using Excel for Windows desktop (latest version)

You can't use rich text editing through formula output, so unfortunately this isn't something you can do through text. You may however be able to create static values through vba and partially bold from that

Why not split them in columns?
